# Black/Dark/Night mode PDF/PPT Viewer MacOS?

Tags: pdf-viewer, macos, pdf-editor, dark-theme

I read a lot during the night and I have so many books in the .pdf .pptx format that my eyes get strained during whole reading sessions. on an average, I roughly read 200 pages daily.

The thing is I have all these .pdf files with a white background. And I am using macOS Catalina, I was hoping to find a macOS app that allows me to invert the color of the PDF while reading ( without permanently saving changes to it)

Is there any such good .pdf/ .ppt reader/viewer available on Store or over the internet(as in .dmg package) for free?